# Confusion Matrix only shows diagonal values for selected labels despite misclassifications

Tags: scikit-learn, classification, confusion-matrix, multiclass-classification

I'm trying to create a confusion matrix for a subset of labels from my data. Despite having misclassified rows, the resulting confusion matrix shows zeros everywhere except the diagonal. Am I missing something?

Here is the code:

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
    
confusion_df = pd.read_csv("./confusion_data.csv")
confusion_df.head() # this dataframe contains true and predicted values of all the test observations
    
selected_labels = [14, 30, 57, 79, 83, 98, 101, 105, 137, 163]
    
# Filter the dataframe to keep only rows from selected labels list
filtered_df = confusion_df[(confusion_df['True'].isin(selected_labels))]
filtered_df = filtered_df.reset_index(drop=True)

# Generate the confusion matrix
confusion_mat = confusion_matrix(filtered_df['True'], filtered_df['Predicted'], labels=selected_labels)
```

After running this code, my confusion matrix looks like this:

```
array([[1602,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0],
       [   0, 1601,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0],
       [   0,    0, 1601,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0],
       [   0,    0,    0, 1597,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0],
       [   0,    0,    0,    0, 1601,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0],
       [   0,    0,    0,    0,    0, 1600,    0,    0,    0,    0],
       [   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0, 1596,    0,    0,    0],
       [   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0, 1599,    0,    0],
       [   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0, 1569,    0],
       [   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0, 1602]],
      dtype=int64)
```

I expected some non-zero values off the diagonal, given that I have 45 misclassified rows. Is there a mistake in my code?

Comment: @DataJanitor, If it is a binary classification then the matrix will have only 4 fields as you said. But if there are N classes, then there will be a matrix with shape N x N

Comment: Did you habe the time to test my solution? If so, does it help you?

Answer (score 0):

To use the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html):

> Compute confusion matrix to evaluate the accuracy of a classification.
>
> By definition a confusion matrix  C is such that  C_ij is equal to the
> number of observations known to be in group i and predicted to be in
> group j .

And the main example:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
y_true = [2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1]
y_pred = [0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2]
confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
array([[2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 2]])
```

In your case you also don't have binary classification, to explain the main example. There are three prediction values: 0,1,2 and three possible outcomes. The function returns:

```
Cndarray of shape (n_classes, n_classes)
Confusion matrix whose i-th row and j-th column entry indicates the number of samples with true label being i-th class and predicted label being j-th class.
```

so the shape is (3,3) . So the matrix is:

```
    predicted  0   1  2
true
0              2   0  0
1              0   0  1
2              1   0   2
```

your confusion matrix makes sense, if there are no double values in your true and predictions values, it makes sense that you only have the diagonal filled.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I see an issue. You only filter for the selected labels in the `'True'` column, but not in the `'Predicted'` column.

When you compute the confusion matrix with `labels=selected_labels`, it looks for matches and misclassifications only among those selected labels for both the `'True'` and `'Predicted'` classes. Since your `'Predicted'` labels aren't filtered to only include `selected_labels`, any prediction not belonging to `selected_labels` is effectively ignored, causing off-diagonal elements to be zero.

So you want to filter for both, the true **or** (inclusive) the predicted column:

```py
# Filter the dataframe to keep only rows where either 'True' or 'Predicted' is in selected_labels list
filtered_df = confusion_df[(confusion_df['True'].isin(selected_labels)) | (confusion_df['Predicted'].isin(selected_labels))]
```